# Slightly modified program for the A345253 such that specific partial sums equal A066258

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, permutations, fibonacci-numbers

- Let $F(n)$ be [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045) i.e. Fibonacci numbers. Here
  $$
  F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2), \\
  F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1
  $$
- Let $a(n)$ be [A345253](https://oeis.org/A345253) i.e. maximal Fibonacci tree: arrangement of the positive integers as labels of a complete binary tree.

There is a PARI/GP program due to **Kevin Ryde**:

```
a(n) = my(x=0, y=0); for(i=0, logint(n, 2), [x, y]=[y+1, x+y]; if(bittest(n, i), [x, y]=[y, x+y])); y;
```

We can slightly modify it by

```
bittest(n, i) -> !bittest(n, i)
```

- Let $b(n)$ be an integer sequence obtained from the program given above with mentioned modification.

The sequence begins with
$$
0, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 12, 9, 8, 6, 8, 6, 5, 4, 33, 25, 22, 17, 21
$$

- Let $c(n)$ be an integer sequence such that $c(1)=1$ and if $x$ is a term, then so are $2x$, $4x+1$ and $4x+3$.

The sequence begins with
$$
1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23
$$

- Let $d(n)$ be [A000975](https://oeis.org/A000975) i.e. the $n$-th number without consecutive equal binary digits.

The sequence begins with
$$
0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 21, 42, 85, 170, 341, 682, 1365, 2730, 5461, 10922, 21845
$$

- Let $e(n)$ be [A066258](https://oeis.org/A066258) i.e.
  $$
  e(n) = F(n)^2F(n+1)
  $$

I conjecture that the sequence $b(c(n))+1$ is a permutation of natural numbers.

I also conjecture that
$$
\sum\limits_{i=d(n-1)+1}^{d(n)}(b(c(i))+1)=e(n).
$$

Here is the PARI/GP program to check it numerically:

```
b(n) = my(x=0, y=0); for(i=0, logint(n, 2), [x, y]=[y+1, x+y]; if(!bittest(n, i), [x, y]=[y, x+y])); y;
b1(n) = if(n < 2, n, (n%2 == 0 && b1(n/2)) || (n%4 == 1 && b1((n-1)/4)) || (n%4 == 3 && b1((n-3)/4)))
d(n) = (4*2^n - 3 - (-1)^n) / 6
b2(n) = my(s = 2^(n-1), A = 0); for(i = 1, d(n) - d(n-1), while(!b1(s), s++); A += (b(s)+1); s++); A
test(n) = b2(n) == fibonacci(n)^2*fibonacci(n+1)
```

Is there a way to prove it?